# Object.assign not transforming to _extend in react-d3-shape

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I have transform-object-assign in webpack, and the file is processed through babel, but one Object.assign isn't converted to _extend in pie.js.

The file (when you npm it), already has _extend for a few Object.assigns in it, but that one particular one remains. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

My whole code is filled with Object.assigns that are transformed to _extend.

Comment: Not really an answer, but why not just use `babel-polyfill` or `core-js` which will actually polyfill `Object.assign`?

Comment: babel-loader wouldn't touch pie.js if it is in node modules folder and you have configured `ignore node modules directory` in webpack configuration

Comment: @Deadfish I will look into it. babel still processes that file though, I know that since it changes some of the stuff in it. I will double check it tomorrow though. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @DavidGilbertson It's not my choice to make actually. I will talk to the CTO and see what he has to say. Thanks

Comment: Tell him a commenter on the internet told you to do it :)